# AngularJS Directive Default Options Cloning

Tags: angularjs

I have a angularjs directive that I crafted.  It has a defaults object that looks like:

```
module.constant('tableDefaults', {
    hasHeader: true,
    paging: {
         autoPageSize: true,
         count: undefined,
         pageSize: undefined
    }
});
```

the directive consumes that constant and merges the options passed in like:

```
module.directive('ngTable', function ($rootScope, tableDefaults) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        require: '^ngModel',
        templateUrl: 'common/components/table/views/table.tpl.html',
        controller: function(){
            // freaks out if removed ...
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes, ctrls) {
            if(!$scope.tableOptions) $scope.tableOptions = {}
            $scope.tableOptions = angular.copy(tableDefaults, $scope.tableOptions);
        } 
    };
});
```

I pass options in like:

```
<div ng-table="{ paging: { count: 100 } }" />
```

problem is now in my paging object, none of the other options are there.  I've been looking at `angular.extend` vs `$.extend` and realize I could probably use `$.extend` to accomplish this but I'm trying to rid my app of jquery.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem here but I see `tableOptions` correctly set to `tableDefaults`. I don't know if the additional scope created by `transclude` could be a problem here (I removed it in my demo), but I dont' see how. Check the `console.debug`: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/6z7kH/)

Comment: I updated it, and now it works. However, be aware that it's creating an isolated scope for each directive instance. But since each one gets its own options, it's probably what you wanted. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/simonedavico/QPHy7/1/)

Comment: Awesome, what about if parent's modify the options, will that still work?

Comment: It will, but to modify the options you have to pass them as a variable to your directive and not simply as an anonymous object. Unless in your ngTable controller you provide a function to set/extend/modify `$scope.ngTable`.